# Comparing variables within classes in python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a method(**it**) that compares the size (area) of the rectangle with the area of another rectangle passed as a parameter:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
       self.width = x
       self.height = y

    def area(self):
       a = self.width * self.height
       return a

    def __it__(self,second):
       return self.area < second.area
```

But I keep getting error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: Rectangle() < Rectangle()
```

I'm not to sure how to fix this problem

Answer (score 4):

You had a typo.  It's `__lt__`, not `__it__`, and you need to call the `area()` as a function unless you set that as a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

Fixing all that...

```
>>> class Rectangle:
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...        self.width = x
...        self.height = y
...     def area(self):
...        a = self.width * self.height
...        return a
...     def __lt__(self,second):
...        return self.area() < second.area()
... 
>>> Rectangle(1,3) > Rectangle(4,5)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Area is a method, you're using it as though it's a variable. Adding parens should fix it (and if you're trying to do less than, it should be `__lt__`):

```
def __lt__(self, second):
    return self.area() < second.area()
```